# How To get Chat History from XMPP for ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am new to XMPP and ejabberd.

and I need to get chat history from ejabberd with XMPP.

I did Googling but didn't got satisfactory Answer.

Any link or idea will be great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#modmam), you need to enable mod_mam in your configuration by adding mod_mam to the list of modules. You also need to specify some of the options as given in the documentation. For eg:

```
mod_mam: 
  default: roster
  request_activates_archiving: true
  assume_mam_usage: if_enabled
```

The default option is never, so you need to set the configuration accordingly.

Comment: Is there any tutorial to retrieve chat history using XMPPHP library?

Comment: @mayurpanchal - Were you able to fetch the archived messages via some APIs?

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable `mod_mam` module in ejabberd and implement [XEP-0313: Message Archive Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html).

Comment: Is there a way to fetch the archived messages via some APIs?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast Did you find any solution?

Comment: I dont remember. Was a long time back. Nonetheless, you can definitely create your custom API and call `os.command`, this would certainly help you out.. But I don;t exactly remember whether there was a default api for not.