# ejabberd get chat history of particular users

Tags: reactjs, xml, xmpp, ejabberd

i built a react client-side app for `ejabberd` using [xmpp-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@xmpp/client) , everything is working fine so far, I can chat between 2 users, and now I'm trying to fetch the chat history between 2 users, I searched google for this found some examples and articles related to this, here are links I followed

1. [server-setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38244110/how-to-get-chat-history-from-xmpp-for-ejabberd)
2. [xep-0313](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html#example-22)

here is the code I have tried

```
await xmppData.send(
  xml(
    "iq",
    {
      type: "set",
      to: "admin@chats.samaaro.com",
      from: userData.email,
      id: xmppData.jid._resource,
    },
    xml(
      "query",
      {
        xmlns: "urn:xmpp:mam:1",
        queryid: queryId,
      },
      xml(
        "x",
        {
          xmlns: "jabber:x:data",
          type: "submit",
        },
        xml(
          "field",
          {
            var: "FORM_TYPE",
            type: "hidden",
          },
          xml("value", {}, "prasanna@example.com")
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

in response I'm getting like below

> attrs: {xmlns: 'http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'}
> children: Array(3)
> 0: Element
> attrs: {}
> children: ['821']
> name: "count"
> parent: Element {name: 'set', parent: Element, children: Array(3), attrs: {…}}
> [[Prototype]]: Object
> 1: Element
> attrs: {}
> children: ['1648729284714751']
> name: "first"
> parent: Element {name: 'set', parent: Element, children: Array(3), attrs: {…}}
> [[Prototype]]: Object
> 2: Element
> attrs: {}
> children: ['1652268849881814']
> name: "last"
> parent: Element {name: 'set', parent: Element, children: Array(3), attrs: {…}}
> [[Prototype]]: Object
> length: 3
> [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
> name: "set"

the question is why I'm getting the `count`, `last`, and `first` instead of the chat history, and how can I get the previous chats instead of the `count, first, last`?

any help or suggestions are really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use the most simple example query:  get all messages stored for your account: https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html#example-2

If that works, try to get all the messages stored for your account when conversating with a specific contact: https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html#example-6

I know nothing about xmpp-react, so I tested this using a desktop XMPP client.

I use Tkabber, but you can try Gajim, Psi or other well known XMPP client: they usually have a "XML console", or some similar name.

In those windows in those clients you can put XML copied from XEP-0313 (maybe you need to change the JIDs), and see how it works. I tried example 2 and example 6, both return the messages correctly.

You can do like me: try with a well known client, writing the XML stanzas manually, and check they work correctly. Then, you can return to your react client, and try to write similar XML stanzas.

Comment: hi badlop, thank you for your response, above i posted the answer how i managed to get the chat history

Answer (score 0):

here is below if somebody is trying to get it done,

```
await xmppData.send(
  xml(
    "iq",
    {
      type: "set",
      to: "admin@example.com", // admin email
      from: userData.email, // current user email
      id: xmppData.jid, // jid of the current user
    },
    xml(
      "query",
      {
        xmlns: "urn:xmpp:mam:2",
      },
      xml(
        "x",
        {
          xmlns: "jabber:x:data",
          type: "submit",
        },
        xml(
          "field",
          {
            var: "FORM_TYPE",
            type: "hidden",
          },
          xml("value", {}, "urn:xmpp:mam:2")
        ),
        xml(
          "field",
          {
            var: "with",
          },
          xml("value", {}, toChatWith.recipientName) // another person email
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

getting a response from XMPP

```
 if (stanza.is("message")) {
      const { children } = stanza;
      const MessageChild = children[0]?.children[0]?.children[0];
      let from = MessageChild?.attrs?.from;
      let to = MessageChild?.attrs?.to;
        setPreMessages((oldMsg) => [
          ...oldMsg,
          {
            msg: MessageChild.children[2].children.toString(),
            sender: from,
          },
        ]);
    }
```